# Javascript abstract figures following mouse

Tags: javascript, html, effect

I just found a very cool effect that I would love to implement on website. The effect can be seen here: http://whois.domaintools.com/

As you can see, some kind of gif is following the mouse around. I think this look extremely cool, and I would love to know how its made.

So here's the question: How can this in fact be made (javascript is MUCH preffered) Keep in mind that this effect only occurs inside the header of the site.

Answer (score 0):

It is made by javascript. You create a canvas element and javascript draws some randomly positioned dots and lines between them.

Because javascript is client language, you can view the source. The file you are looking for is [there](http://whois.domaintools.com/composite/code.js?wStatusBar=compiled-wStatusBar&wBootstrapLayout=/space/vhosts/img.domaintools.com/htdocs/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min&wScrollingNav=compiled-scrolling_nav,compiled-konami&mWhois=landing,jquery_easing_v1.3,rAF,TweenLite.min,spiders&wGoogleAds=google_ads_utilities&ext=js&hash=9210573229a28af12ab25cdaa6ab96d8).

Comment: Is this not in any way possible to make more compact, or somehow using a GIF image? Maybe have a large hidden GIF filling the entire header, with opacity of 0, and then apply a greater opacity within x pixels of the cursor??

Comment: Yes, you can create some gif image which is mostly transparent, only with those points and lines etc. But it won't be random, as it is in the example.

Comment: It it possible to make a more compact and less complex version of this?
Say, create the random dots and lines with movement, within a radius of 300 px around the cursor, and then apply som edge fading?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an image to move with your mouse, you'll need to bind to the `mousemove` event. That's what's happening on that site, too, though I think it's more complex than just moving a gif along with your mouse.

But if you want to make a gif appear under your cursor as it moves, you can use this:

```
// when mouse enters whatever element you want 
// (in this case the header), create the image
window.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'http://path.to.image';
    document.body.appendChild(img);
});

// move image according to mouse position
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    img.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
    img.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';

});

// remove image when mouse leaves element
window.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    document.body.removeChild(img);
    img = null;
});
```

Comment: I would actually preffer the randomly generated dots and lines from the website :)